# Moving through every character in a string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

I am trying to go through every string index and print the even indexes first and then print all the odd indexes. However I am getting a segmentation error and I don't know what it is caused by.

Here is my code:

```
int sum;
vector<string> array;
string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    temp = array[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
        sum = j;
        if (sum % 2 == 0) {
            cout << array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
cout << " ";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    temp = array[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
        sum = j;
        if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            cout << array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the point of variable `sum`?

Comment: You don't need the `sum % 2`.  You should set the increments to `i += 2` and likewise for `j`.  Start at 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vector<string> array` is an *empty* `vector`, but you're trying to access its `i`th value with `cin >> array[i];` in the first loop, thus getting out of bounds (*there's no `i`th index*!) and a segfault.

You should *append* new values to the vector dynamically or pre-allocate the needed amount of space:

```
// in the first loop
string test;

cin >> test;
array.push_back(test);
```

Another option:

```
// change the declaration
vector<string> array(num); // a vector of size num

// or pre-allocate memory after initialisation 
vector<string> array;
array.resize(num);
// then the loop...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not populating the array correctly, so your loops are going out of bounds.

Try something more like this instead:

```
vector<string> array;
string temp;

array.resize(num);
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    cin >> array[i];
}
/* Alternatively:
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    cin >> temp;
    array.push_back(temp);
}
*/
/* Alternatively:
copy_n(istream_iterator<string>(cin), num, back_inserter(array));
*/

for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    temp = array[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j += 2)
    {
        cout << temp[j];
    }
}

cout << " ";

for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    temp = array[i];
    for(int j = 1; j < temp.size(); j += 2)
    {
        cout << temp[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the size of the `std::vector <std::string> array` and you are trying to index it which gives segmentation fault. You can use `array.push_back()` to insert the values, or you have to define the size while declaring the vector.

Either:

```
std::vector <std::string> array (num); // given num is known beforehand
```

Or:

```
vector<string> array;
string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cin >> temp;
    array.push_back(temp);
}
```